# Unable to load or bind string value to input[type=time]

Tags: angularjs, html

I have the following html input inside and ng-repeat:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label small">Time</label>
  <input type="time" class="form-control" ng-model="schedule.time" required />
</div>
```

Now this is inside an edit form.  When the page loads it GETs the data from the server and loads into their respective input fields.  All other input fields seem to be showing except the time.

I thought it might be the format of the value so I changed it from just:

> 20:45:00

to

```
{
    "date":"2016-11-24 20:45:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone"
    :"UTC"
}
```

Using Carbon but that also didn't work.  The data still doesn't show in the input field.  However when I change it from time to text it shows.

Comment: Are u getting any error in browser console ?

Comment: Please share your JS source

Comment: No I am not getting any errors in my browser console and what do you mean by JS source?

Comment: You javascript attempt I mean in order to get a relative answer, otherwise I can give you a generic approach

Comment: I'm not doing anything special in my javascript, just assigning the returned data.  Like I said it works when I change from input time to input text.

Answer (score 1):

If we say that you want to display this time: `20:45:00` then in your JS code you should do something like this in order to pass data into an `input[time]` field:

```
$scope.myDate = new Date();
$scope.myDate.setHours(20,45,0)
```

In your case can simplified by using your obj:

```
{
    "date":"2016-11-24 20:45:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone"
    :"UTC"
}
```

You can do:

```
$scope.schedule.time = new Date(obj.date);
```

Check more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assigning string into ng-model which should be Date.Before assigning to model convert it to Date from string.

Try below code. It might help u.

```
$scope.time = new Date(obj.date);
```

Please find the working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Uv4wd0QFKgKJXuRkVJY6?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Your date string needs to be parsed into Date object and then you can use an angular filter to display just the time. The angular docs have a good example.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D